# HtmlUnit - Class not found in src folder but run in test folder

Tags: java, maven, htmlunit

I am programming in Java using Maven/Eclipse.

I am able to run HtmlUnit fine when running from a Unit Test. (test/)

However when I try to use the same code in the src/ folder, I receive `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` messages. The only way I have been able to resolve them is to go and manually add all the jars to the build path. But this doesn't make sense to me as the jar file shows up in my Maven Dependencies.

pom.xml (there are more dependencies in the actual pom file)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The Sample block of HtmlUnit code

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
System.out.println("Executing Pages JavaScript for " + config.executeJavaScriptTime + " seconds...");                       webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(config.executeJavaScriptTime);
dom = cleaner.clean(page.asXml());
html = cleaner.getInnerHtml(dom);
webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test scope which is applied to your dependency means that it is not available on the compile classpath. This way, the code you ship does not depend on test code. A more complete explanation can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). If the project you are building is intended to be only tests, you should remove the scope tag to let it take the default scope, compile. But in general it is correct that your shipping code, built from src, shouldn't depend on JUnit, a testing library.

Comment: yeah that makes perfect sense, I didn't even notice that little tag. Serves me right for copy/pasting the dependency. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

As of now the only working hack I have found is to create a method annotated as `@Test` and run the crawler as a JUnit Test.

i.e.

```
public class Crawler() {

    @Test
    public void runAsTest() {
        Crawler crawler = new Crawler();
        String[] urls = new String[]{
                "http://www.url.com/1",
                "http://www.url.com/2",
                "http://www.url.com/3"
            };
        crawler.crawl(urls);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 15); // without this the unit test exits too early
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  // the rest of the class definition

}
```

I would like to be able to run this from a standard main method, i.e.

```
public class Crawler() {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Crawler crawler = new Crawler();
        String[] urls = new String[]{
                "http://www.url.com/1",
                "http://www.url.com/2",
                "http://www.url.com/3"
            };
        crawler.crawl(urls);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 15); // without this the unit test exits too early
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  // the rest of the class definition

}
```